# How to send a request to a file php using jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two buttons: one for create a table in my database and another to delete the table, but when I click on the button "Drop Table" the message shown is: "Error create table: Table 'post' already exists", because it enters the first if on php file. I can not find how to solve this.

**Here go my code:**

html

```
<button id="loadButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:5px;">Create Table</button>
<button id="deleteButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top:5px;">Drop Table</button>
```

dash.js file

```
$('#loadButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'connectdb.php',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
$('#deleteButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'connectdb.php',
        data: "drop",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

connectdb.php file

```
// Create table
$sql="CREATE TABLE Post( 
    id_post int Primary Key, 
    titulo varchar(100) not null, 
    imagem longblob,
    descricao varchar(1000) not null,
    hashtag varchar(100) not null
)";

// Execute query
if(!isset($_POST["drop"])){
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  echo "Table created with success";
} else {
  echo "Error create table: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
}

if (isset($_POST["drop"])) {
    $sql1="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Post;";
    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) {
        echo "Table deleted";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are sending a value, not a key -> `data: "drop",`. Try `data: {drop:'drop'}`. Although it is not a great idea to create/drop tables like this.

Comment: thanks it works :)... Why you say that it is not a great idea to create/drop tables like this? In future I will create table manually

Comment: In order for this to be safe, you will need to make sure your `connectdb.php` is password protected, or anyone will be able to delete your tables by accessing the url directly.

Comment: Ah ok! you are right, so anyone could make sql injection. I will follow your advice :). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are don't sending post value. It's should look like this:

```
$('#deleteButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'connectdb.php',
        data: { drop: "Drop value that you need"}
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```